# dial windows serial modem from php

Tags: php, windows, serial-port, modem

I am trying to dial a phone number from php (i have a client list in a database, and thought i could use it to ring them when i click on their name

here is my code, it doesn't seem to work. I can hear the phone line click, but it doesn't seem to dial. maybe i am missing some command that needs to be sent prior to atdt?

```
$device = "COM4";

exec("mode $device BAUD=9600 PARITY=n DATA=8 STOP=1 xon=off octs=off rts=on");

$comport = fopen($device, "r+b");

if ($comport === false) {
    die ("Failed opening com port");
} else {
    echo "Com Port Open";
}

stream_set_blocking($comport, 0);

$atcmd = "ATDT222222222222\r"; // dial fake number
if (fwrite($comport, $atcmd ) === false) {
    die ("Failed writing to com port"); 
} else {
    echo "Wrote $atcmd to com port";
}

sleep(10); // added fix to make program work, was closing port too soon for it to dial

fclose($comport);
```

Comment: Why open non-blocking if you are just going to sleep anyway? Isn't it better to just let the script block then close when done? The sleep() hack is racey.

Comment: I am not sure why it uses non-blocking, i was using a class php_serial i found on the web, and just cut it down to the bare basics for the purpose of this question.  

I don't know enough about ports, blocking/non-blocking etc so i left it as i found it.

I agree using sleep (10) is a bit racey but for the limited use this script will get, i will work fine for me. good point though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved, silly me

all that is needed is a sleep() before the fclose 
it was just closing the port before it could actually do any dialing
apart from that it seems to work fine

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$comport = fopen($device, "w+");
...
$atcmd = "ATDT222222222222\r\n";
```

Comment: same thing, modem clicks, no dialing